# using data on the view from async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation

I'm using the geolocator plugin to retrieve my current location and add a pin to the page. Here is the service for this:

tasks.cs

```
public async Task<Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position> GetDeviceCurrentLocation()
{
    try
    {
        var locator = Plugin.Geolocator.CrossGeolocator.Current;
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

        var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        if (position != null)
        {
            return position;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Unable to get location, may need to increase timeout: " + ex);
    }

    return new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position();
}
```

I'm trying to use it in the view like this :

```
public MapPage(List<Models.xxx> xxx, Models.yyy yyy )
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Tasks ts = new Tasks();
  var myLocation = ts.GetDeviceCurrentLocation();
  var latitudeIm = myLocation.Result.Latitude;
  var longitudeIm = myLocation.Result.Longitude;
  var pin1 = new Pin
  {
    Type = PinType.Place,
    Position = new Position(latitudeIm, longitudeIm),
    Title = "My Location"
  };
  customMap.Pins.Add(pin1);
}
```

My application breaks when I try this code `var latitudeIm = myLocation.Result.Latitude;`
I guess since I have a async task the result must be `awaited`. Any idea how can I use the **`public async Task<Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position> GetDeviceCurrentLocation()`** data in my view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `await` for async method;

```
var myLocation = await ts.GetDeviceCurrentLocation();
var latitudeIm = myLocation.Latitude;
var longitudeIm = myLocation.Longitude;
```

You should decorate all methods as `async` completely. If you don't able to apply it (I wouldn't recommend it), you could use `ConfigureAwait` to prevent deadlock;

```
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);

var myLocation = ts.GetDeviceCurrentLocation().Result;//Also don't hit the Result twice
var latitudeIm = myLocation.Latitude;
var longitudeIm = myLocation.Longitude;
```

Comment: I can't await `ts.GetDeviceCurrentLocation()` . See edit.
Should I create a model? With just the latitude and longitude properties? And what do you mean controller? I don't have a controller in the project. I'm not using MVC pattern.

Comment: I cant use `var myLocation = await ts.GetDeviceCurrentLocation()` this line cause I'm trying to access the data on the constructor of the page and it is not async, that's why it will throw me an error. If I could use await than the problem would be solved. :/

Comment: Well, you can use "ConfigureAwait" then.

Comment: I tried it but still it's a deadlock situation and the still the app breaks. Is there any other way to do it? Any other approach?

Comment: Would you try  to remove ConfigureAwait and apply Task.Run; "Task.Run(() => ts.GetDeviceCurrentLocation()).Result;" But as i said, it is not a good practice. It could be better to decorate your methods in async completely.

Comment: How am I supposed to decorate my method in async completely in this case ?

Comment: There is a good article here. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/

Comment: It's a dead link.

Comment: Are you sure ??

Comment: Now I'm able to open it. @stormcloak

Comment: I still couldn't find any solution. I know how to use async and await together. I think my question is pretty clear and pretty simple I just don't know how to do use the returned data of the task in the code-behind of the view. How would you do it?! A little help would be highly appreciated @stormcloak

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163267/discussion-between-stormcloak-and-john).